# Can I access to DataFrame index and use it when calculating something in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, read-data

I'm reading the data I'm working on and making it organized with the following codes.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv").assign(date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['date']))
.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'), pd.Grouper(key='item_id')]).count().reset_index()
.pivot('date', 'item_id').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This way I can see the indexes and their values.

[image: output]

What should I do if I want to operate using the values in the indexes? How can I access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat your index as a normal column:

```
df['new_column'] = df.index
```

Or

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to set `drop=False` to insert the index into the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, you are right!